# How to get all the terms from a custom hierarchical taxonomy via REST api?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, rest-api

This post can be a solution, but I guess there could be something more linear or native:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462187/wordpress-rest-api-v2-how-to-list-taxonomy-terms

The official REST API guide is not really clear to me, and doesn't have much examples.

I've got a custom 'dealer_areas' taxonomy, hierarchical (continents > countries > regions).

I need to build a small js app based on that and, even if I could use the 'regular' admin-ajax way, this time I'd like to use the REST API instead.

I use https://httpie.org/ client (just to have some syntax sugar and pretty printing), but it could be any. If I ask for this, I get some terms, but not all:

```
http GET dev.example.com/my-site/wp-json/wp/v2/dealer_areas
```

I get terms from every nesting level, but not all.. And they're not returned based on post counts, so it really seems there's no logic in this.

Anyway, I'd like a direct way to get all the terms from all nesting levels (even empty ones).

Is there any or am I forced to create a custom route?

Comment: we are speaking of rest api here.

Comment: of course, but I was asking if there's some more linear/native way other than registering a custom route. I already can do it with custom routes, that's not an issue.

Comment: OK, I understand